# How to use PasswordBox as TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, passwordbox

I have a `PasswordBox` and I need to use this control **even** as a `TextBox`.
I need to display normal text and not the typical black dots

[image]

Is there a property to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Then why not use a normal TextBox..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Because I need a PasswordBox

Comment: And... Why do you need a PasswordBox?

Comment: you are not making sense.. what's the difference unless you are saying that you want to display the password in plaintext..then what's the use of having a Password TextBox..?

Comment: @Damascus because for most of the time i need the typical black dots, but i need also normal text, is it so difficult to understand?

Comment: So you want the textbox to show random letters as the user types in his password instead of black dots?

Comment: @JaneDoe not random letters, but the text i write (as TextBox)

Comment: that makes literally no sense in that case, why dont you just use a textbox? what is so special about a paswordbox that makes you want to use it?

Comment: Nick please clean up your explanation of what you are looking to do. I can feel a CLOSE VOTE coming on here..

Comment: Jane he is confusing himself or he is not familiar with TextBox Control I am moving on out of this discussion

Comment: Yes it is difficult to understand. A `PasswordBox` is designed to hide what you are writing. If you don't want to hide it, use  `TextBox`. You can just for example use a hidden `TextBox` and put it to Visible whenever you need it

Comment: Then why don't you use a TextBox when you need normal text and a PasswordBox when you don't, either hiding the one you don't need based on whatever logic you use to decide, or using different templates based on that logic?

Comment: What functionality of a password box do you need that keeps you from just using a textbox instead?

Comment: @Nick: Wait... so do you want to display black dots, or do you **not** want to display black dots?

Comment: So you want something that lets it normally show black dots, but when you click a checkbox to disable the black dot hiding?

Comment: THIS is probably the funniest exchange of comments I've ever read on SO. Please don't delete this question, mods.

Comment: @Nick: Both in what way? Toggle between them like Xantham suggested, or do you want to display both at the same time (which really doesn't work)?

Comment: Explain exactly how you intend to use this passwordbox/textbox.  Describe the usage.  What will happen to go from black dots to text and back?

Comment: You can't imagine that sometimes one needs a straight textbox and other times a passwordbox? What a bunch of unimaginative people! And I mean that in the friendliest way possible! It's like sometimes you feel like a nut, sometimes you don't. It's clear as a bell to me, I don't see why this seems like rocket science to an English major to you.  Plus 1 to counteract the dumpers.

Comment: @Nick See jvanh1's answer below, would be more plausible, since the UseSystemPasswordChar is a simpler solution.

Comment: @Prisoner couldn't have been stated any better ...it's so frustrating when people find http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions but can't seem to find http://www.google.com LMAO

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is your answer:

1. Use a Textbox
2. When you want the text masked set TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
3. when you want to see the text set TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
4. Profit

Example:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
    }
}
```

Black dots when you want them, words when you don't. You can use what ever trigger/logic you want for the turning on and off but this way you are only using one control and get all the functionality that you specified you needed.

Comment: +1 Much cleaner than my solution. Cheers.

Comment: I didn't realize the missing step before profit on all these lists was: when you want to see the text set TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;     .... I am in the money now!

Comment: but this works just for winforms, the user asked for wpf.

Comment: This property doesn't exist on a WPF textbox.

Answer (score 10):

Your best solution would be to have a Password Box with a checkbox underneath that says "Show characters" and then create a Trigger on the Password Box that overlays a TextBox on it for typing and retrieve the text as appropriate.

Comment: This is probably what the OP is asking for, +1. I've see it done before, though not with the WPF toolkit.

Comment: @jrg You would have to create a Setter that would have a Trigger for when the checkbox is triggered, and somehow add a key to the TextBox that would allow you to retrieve the text from that instead of PasswordBox when PasswordBox is empty, or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Stop dumping on him people.

Answer (score 0):

Superimpose a `TextBox` and a `PasswordBox`, keeping only one `Visible` at a time. When you want to switch over, copy over the value of the active one to the other one, and switch their visibilities. Simple.

Answer (score -1):

I think everybody agrees on this very basic solution: Use a `TextBox` if you want to display what the user is typing.

Comment: And what do you use if you don't want to, at a given moment?

Comment: The basic fact is that I don't understand why would you need a `PasswordBox` showing the inputs. That's exactly be a `TextBox`. If you need to alternate between the two modes, you can still put a visible `PasswordBox` on an invisible `TextBox`, bind them to the same property, and play with their `Visibility` . `PasswordBox` is designed to hide what you are typing, I don't think you should use it showing what we type

Comment: I agree. The OP has gotten this by now, surely.  There is a reason for wanting this, however.  Hasn't anyone gotten the idea that ALWAYS obscuring password input is kind of stupid?  It's late at night, nobody is with you, and you keep screwing up your password because you can't see what you're typing because you're tired.  Why not have a checkbox there that toggles to visible password, so you can see what the heck you are typing.  It's insane to always force it.