# C# / WPF Unmask password inside the passwordBox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, passwords, passwordbox

How could I unmasked and masked the password inside the passwordBox whenever I click the checkBox? I'm using C# WPF template.

Here is  my .XAML code:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox_password" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5" Height="25" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_showPassword" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,5" Content="show password" Checked="checkBox_showPassword_Checked" Unchecked="checkBox_showPassword_Unchecked" />
```

Here is my .CS code:

```
private void checkBox_showPassword_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // what to do here ?
    }

    private void checkBox_showPassword_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // what to do here ?
    }
```

Or is there another way to do it in WPF?

Comment: look here, you can use a Textbox instead to get that functionality
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517969/how-to-use-passwordbox-as-textbox

Comment: sorry, that seems to work only in winforms

Comment: here there is another option
http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [showing password characters on some event for passwordbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091466/showing-password-characters-on-some-event-for-passwordbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link will bring you to the answer you are looking for my good sir. Mr Lamas did a great job of answering the how-to so I'd rather redirect you to the answer :)

[showing password characters on some event for passwordbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091466/showing-password-characters-on-some-event-for-passwordbox)

Comment: The comments there are telling this is not working anymore

Answer (score 9):

It's very simple to do that.
First you should to add the value `PasswordChar` in your PasswordBox:

```
<PasswordBox Name="PasswordHidden" PasswordChar="•"/>
```

Next under the PasswordBox tag you should to add a TextBox with `Visibility` value setted to Hidden:

```
<TextBox Name="PasswordUnmask" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

And a trigger to show / hide the password, for example a simple text or a button. In my case I'm using a simple text.

```
<TextBlock Name="ShowPassword"/>
```

Next you need to add 3 different events in the trigger element, for example (this is valid for TextBlock or Image, if you want to use a Button you should to choose another events):

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ShowPassword" Text="SHOW" PreviewMouseDown="ShowPassword_PreviewMouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="ShowPassword_PreviewMouseUp" MouseLeave="ShowPassword_MouseLeave"/>
```

The events are `PreviewMouseDown` `PreviewMouseUp` and `MouseLeave` but you can choose the appropriate event for your situation.

Now in your code you need to program the functions:

```
private void ShowPassword_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => ShowPasswordFunction();
private void ShowPassword_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => HidePasswordFunction();
private void ShowPassword_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => HidePasswordFunction();

private void ShowPasswordFunction()
{
    ShowPassword.Text = "HIDE";
    PasswordUnmask.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    PasswordHidden.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    PasswordUnmask.Text = PasswordHidden.Password;
}

private void HidePasswordFunction()
{
    ShowPassword.Text = "SHOW";
    PasswordUnmask.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    PasswordHidden.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me - Even with bindings to the "ShowPasswordTextBox" - that way I can use bindings as normally for handling the password.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Using MahApps.Metro ... after installing it from nuget.org ... you must use it in the head of your xaml like this
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winf/xaml/controls"

and then ... just use it's style for your PasswordBox  control

```
<PasswordBox  Style="{StaticResource MetroButtonRevealedPasswordBox}" />
```

you can even change the content for the show icon using the controls:PasswordBoxHelper.RevealButtonContent attached property

Comment: Thanks!!! I happen to use **MahApps.Metro** in my app and now that I needed this functionality it was super convenient. I can't believe how easy it was.